# Declaring and accessing the List<int>[][] in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have declared below list:

```
List<int>[][] main=new List<int>[4][];

main[0]=new List<int>[3];
```

I am getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of object", if I try to add element using below statement:

```
main[0][0].add(3);
```

Can you please let me know what's wrong with the statement and the equivalent correct statement ?

Comment: are you trying to create a 3D matrix/array of integers?

Comment: Element `0` of `main[0]` is probably still a null List.  Instantiate it to a new list first.  Please include the actual error (I suspect it's a nullRef exception)

Comment: I need array of integers, but size is dynamic

Comment: "I am getting error" - *what* error? Is it a compiler error or a runtime error? What's the error message? Please be specific in your questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) - after reading the basic description, please make sure to read "**Array Elements**" and "**Jagged Arrays**" sections.

Comment: 'I need array of integers, but size is dynamic' that would just look like this; `List<int>`. Based on the comment and the wackiness of `List<int>[][]` I'm not sure if you actually want guidance in using that structure of you're actually looking for something much much simpler like a 2d array or a plain `List<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This instruction `main[0]=new List<int>[3];`will create an object of type Array of List of size 3 and will allocate the necessary space on the heap for that object but it does not instanciate each element. Each element will have the default value equal to `null`

Therefore `main[0][0].add(3);`is an attempt to call add on a null object. You should prior to this line have something like: `main[0][0] = new List<int>();`

Answer (score 0):

You've left out a step to initiliaze one of the dimensions. The first one is `main[0]=new List<int>[3];` but you also need `main[0][0] = new List<int>();`

So something like this should do it;

```
        List<int>[][] main = new List<int>[3][];
        main[0] = new List<int>[3];
        main[0][0] = new List<int>();

        main[0][0].Add(1000);

        Console.WriteLine(main[0][0].FirstOrDefault()); // 1000
```